# Saving a rubber tree

Tags: diagnosis, tree-care, plant-recommendations

A friend gave me a 4 month old rubber tree about 8 months ago.

Unfortunately its gone from being healthy, with 10 leaves to rundown and leafless.   It is just inside an east facing window, is not being over-watered and has a yellow hue to it.

**I noticed my cat has been crapping in the plant.** about 3 weeks ago. I gently removed the plant, dumped out the pot soil, washed out the pot and replaced the soil with a bag of indoor potting soil mix with a little black dirt from around the root ball of some hydrangeas.  (At this point the plant still had a couple of leaves left)

On the advice of my partner, I have tonight pulled the final 2 leaves off as they were in bad shape (we were concerned that the leaves are robbing it of the energy it required to bounce back) but now I am worried its not going to survive.

Below are the pics of the top/bottom of the 2 final leaves removed, and of the now bare trunk.

What are the chances the tree will grow back - and is there anything I can do to encourage it ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd cut off the rotted parts at top. And sprinkle black pepper around the soil so the cat stays away.